# Texto parece cheio de lixo depois de digitado

Tags: c, string, memória

Comecei a criar uma aplicação de recolha e uso de dados com o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int idade = 0;
    char nome[20];

    printf("Hello! How old are you? ");
    scanf("%d", &idade);
    while (idade == 0) {
        printf("\nAge cannot be 0 nor be decimal. Re-enter your age: ");
        scanf("%d", &idade);
    }
    printf("And what's your name? (write up to 20 characters, only 1st name) ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);
    printf("\nHello %s, aged %d!\n", nome, idade);

    return 0;
}
```

Mas, depois de compilar com GCC, o output é:

> ```
> Hello! How old are you? 123
> And what's your name? (write up to 20 characters, only 1st name) 
> Hello �����dU��m�, aged 123!
> ```

O que eu tenho que alterar?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

O código tem alguns problemas. Vou resolver alguns, mas ainda não é um código robusto porque ele não testa outros problemas, não entrarei nessas questões.

Um problema é que para ler texto com espaço em branco você precisa usar [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), e precisa tratar a mudança de linha que deve ser trocada para um terminador. O que leva a outro problema: se quer 20 caracteres precisa reservar 21 bytes de *buffer*. E o `scanf()` precisa receber um padrão com a nova linha para não deixar sujeira no *buffer*.

Pelo menos esta é uma solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int idade = 0;
    printf("Hello! How old are you? ");
    scanf("%d\n", &idade);
    while (idade == 0) {
        printf("\nAge cannot be 0 nor be decimal. Re-enter your age: ");
        scanf("%d", &idade);
    }
    char nome[21];
    fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
    nome[strcspn(nome, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("\nHello %s, aged %d!\n", nome, idade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MavRiS). E [no **replit**](https://repl.it/join/vzsuieul-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/GetName.c).

É possível usar um truque com o `scanf()`, mas entenda que em códigos reais esta função raramente é usada para entrada de dados livres:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int idade = 0;
    printf("Hello! How old are you? ");
    scanf("%d\n", &idade);
    while (idade == 0) {
        printf("\nAge cannot be 0 nor be decimal. Re-enter your age: ");
        scanf("%d", &idade);
    }
    char nome[21];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome);
    printf("\nHello %s, aged %d!\n", nome, idade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SIJ9Cq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/acczxghk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/GetName2.c).

Answer (score 3):

### Problema

Esse problema é bem comum para quem está a começar ou não está muito dentro do assunto, e está relacionado com a forma com o `scanf` com `%d` funciona.

Se reparar o `scanf` com `%d` **não consome a quebra de linha**, e por isso permite lhe fazer algo como:

```
int x, y, z;
scanf("%d", &x);
scanf("%d", &y);
scanf("%d", &z);
```

E depois introduzir os valores separados por espaço, assim:

```
10 20 30
```

É importante perceber que apenas pressionou <kbd>Enter</kbd> uma vez mas conseguiu fazer 3 leituras, pelo simples motivo de que elas não lhe consomem a quebra de linha.

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/rYwdIP)

Por isso no seu código, primeiro lê a idade:

```
scanf("%d", &idade);
```

Mas o <kbd>Enter</kbd> ficou no buffer de entrada e quando vai ler o `nome` com:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);
```

A primeira e única coisa que apanha é o <kbd>Enter</kbd>, pois a leitura com `%[^\n]` é até apanhar `\n`.

### Solução

A solução passa por consumir a quebra de linha. Tem pelo menos duas formas simples de o fazer:

- Incluindo um espaço na leitura seguinte:

  ```
  scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome);
  //     ^--- este espaço consome a quebra de linha anterior
  ```

  [Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/FTMo3N)
- Utilizando [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/):

  ```
  fgetc(stdin); //aqui consome a quebra
  scanf("%[^\n]s", nome); // agora lê normalmente
  ```

  [Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/J587ut)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, basta acrescentar esta linha antes do scanf do nome `setbuf(stdin, NULL);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

int idade = 0;
char nome[20];

printf("Hello! How old are you? ");
scanf("%d", &idade);
while (idade == 0) {
    printf("\nAge cannot be 0 nor be decimal. Re-enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &idade);
}
printf("And what's your name? (write up to 20 characters, only 1st name) ");
setbuf(stdin, NULL);    
scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);
printf("\nHello %s, aged %d!\n", nome, idade);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Não, não basta: https://ideone.com/MavRiS

Comment: @Maniero estranho, eu nao tenho esse erro, provavelmente por estar a correr num windows

Comment: Sim, é algo dependente de plataforma, por isso não deve ser usado.

Comment: Não estou a perceber, fiz o teste e deu bem https://ideone.com/uomFIx

Comment: Você não está dando enter na entrada, que é o normal. Não dá para usar algo que depende de como a pessoa entra o dado. Você viu que o teste não funciona, não adianta adaptar o teste pra funcionar, tem que adaptar o código para funcionar.

Comment: Não estou a conseguir de nenhuma forma encontrar a solução

Comment: Vou fazer então.